# How do OpenZeppelin ERC721 tests pass?

Tags: openzeppelin, ganache, erc-721, truffle-test

I don't understand how the following test can pass. I tried it in my application and it fails.

The entry point is the description `'when called by the owner'`.

In this function two test cases are run. Before each test case the token with `tokenId` is transferred to the address stored in `this.to`. After transferring the token approval is deleted.

The test case `transfers the ownership of the given token ID to the given address` because it tests the new owner of the contract.

The second test `'clears the approval for the token ID'`will alway fail because the `transferFunction` in the `beforeEach` function is called again but the token doesn't belong to `owner`anymore.

I'm wondering if the test framework is supposed to behave differently and should delete the state before running a test case. This is not happening with my setup (`ganache-cli@6.1.0, Truffle v4.1.11 (core: 4.1.11, Solidity v0.4.24 (solc-js), Mocha 2.5.3` )

```
beforeEach(async function () {
  this.to = accounts[1];
  await this.token.approve(approved, tokenId, { from: owner });
  await this.token.setApprovalForAll(operator, true, { from: owner });
});

const transferWasSuccessful = function ({ owner, tokenId, approved }) {
  it('transfers the ownership of the given token ID to the given address', async function () {
    const newOwner = await this.token.ownerOf(tokenId);
    newOwner.should.be.equal(this.to);
  });

  it('clears the approval for the token ID', async function () {
    const approvedAccount = await this.token.getApproved(tokenId);
    approvedAccount.should.be.equal(ZERO_ADDRESS);
  });
...
}

const shouldTransferTokensByUsers = function (transferFunction) {
  describe('when called by the owner', function () {
    beforeEach(async function () {
      ({ logs } = await transferFunction.call(this, owner, this.to, tokenId, { from: owner }));
    });
    transferWasSuccessful({ owner, tokenId, approved });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works because a new instance of the contract is created for each test case. This happens in an outside `beforeEach` function which is called before every single test case is run.